# Compiling one .aar library file from multiple modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Hello everyone I have library project that consists from multiple modules :

- module 1
- module 2
- module 3
- module 4

I want to export all four modules as one .aar library file so I'm thinking about generating .aar files for each module and including it to other .aar file I'm not sure if this is going to work or is this good practice so I want your opinions on that ? And what is the best way to compile one .aar file from multiple modules ?

- EDIT :
  I manages to find solution https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar and to get all modules in one .aar file. But since I'm using dagger I get following error :

> stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ldagger/internal/Preconditions .... Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[...

It's seems dependencies don't get included into .aar file.

Comment: you can make a new module (lets name its all-lib) which uses all these modules as dependencies in its gradle, then export that module (all-lib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "standard" way of doing it is to just direct use the modules in the compilation process that will generate the 1 aar.

So let's say `module1` is the main part of the library, you'll have the following on it's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library' // it's a library, generates aar

dependencies {
    // the other modules are dependencies on this one
    compile project(':module2')
    compile project(':module3')
    compile project(':module4')
}
```

Comment: fixed, it will produce aar not jar

Comment: Okey I'll give it a try and depending on that I'll accept your answer.Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @MoshErsan ops, what a bad typo from me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but i think that doesnt include Xml Resources from other modules only from the centre one.