# Prevent resource id collision between modules

Tags: android

I have the following project setup:

```
MyProjectApp/app/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml (layout1)
MyProjectApp/module1/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml (layout2)
```

Now in my `module1`, when I try to do `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);`, it loads the layout from the `app`. To fix this, I could rename my *layout2* so that there is no name collision.

My problem is, when I release my `module1` in AAR format, there is still the possibility of name collision because another project setup may name their own `layout1` the same as my layout in the AAR.

Well, I could rename my `layout2` to a very random name but I don't want that. I want a simple layout name such as *main_activity*.

So the question is, how can I make sure that when I do `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);` inside `module1`, it loads the `layout2` file?

Comment: Have you tried using a FQCN (fully qualified class name) to refer to the `R` file? Unless the `app` and `module1` have the exact same packagename, you could do `myproject.app.R.layout.main_activity` and `myproject.module1.R.layout.main_activity1` and that would avoid the problem. Basically, `module1` should import it's own `R` file, and not the `app` module's `R` file.

Comment: Yes, I tried this: setContentView(com.mycompany.module1.R.layout.main_activity). Still loads the `layout1` instead of `layout2`. @Shark

Comment: ... Are you absolutely sure that the two files are not identical? I mean, if module1.R has, for example, textview named `@+id/text1` and app.R has textview named `@+id/text2`, can your module1 code actually reference `text2` even though it's nonexistant in it's R file?

Comment: @Shark Yes I am sure. module1.R has `text1` while app.R has none. Thus, my module crashes because it could not find `text1`.

Comment: Interesting. what about gradle settings, can you post those? Gradle version and plugin version might be important here, but - is the same problem present if you rename `module1.R.main_activity` to something like `module1.R.main_activity_test` ? I'm thinking that maybe, if `app` has `module1` as a dependency, the dependency resources aren't packaged because android isn't producing a fat AAR. "Similar" problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633799/compiling-one-aar-library-file-from-multiple-modules#39633911)

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890037/packaging-android-aar-that-has-dependencies) but it kinda sounds like AAR packaging is causing problems. Which... shouldn't be a case, as it implies a bug in the packaging itself. So probably something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any resolution. I even tried turning off [Non Transitive R Classes](https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-transitive-r-classes) but did not work.

I ended up renaming my `module1`'s layout file with something like below as suggested in this [blog post](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/resources-collision-without-warning-b29294f518c6):

```
MyProjectApp/module1/src/main/res/module1_main_activity.xml
```